# При добавлении плагина jQuery.scrollSpeed.js сайт при прокрутке "откатывается" назад, это только в Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Ссылка на сайт: https://mixplaster.site/
При прокрутке после того, как отпускаешь колесико мыши, сайт как бы "откатывается" назад, происходит это только в  браузере Chrome. В чем может быть причина?
Началось после добавления плагина jQuery.scrollSpeed.js.
Код плагина:

```js
(function($) {
    
    jQuery.scrollSpeed = function(step, speed, easing) {
        
        var $document = $(document),
            $window = $(window),
            $body = $('html, body'),
            option = easing || 'default',
            root = 0,
            scroll = false,
            scrollY,
            scrollX,
            view;
            
        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)
        
            return false;
            
        $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            
            var deltaY = e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY,
                detail = e.originalEvent.detail;
                scrollY = $document.height() > $window.height();
                scrollX = $document.width() > $window.width();
                scroll = true;
            
            if (scrollY) {
                
                view = $window.height();
                    
                if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            
                    root = (root + view) >= $document.height() ? root : root += step;
                
                if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            
                    root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
                
                $body.stop().animate({
            
                    scrollTop: root
                                    
                }, speed, option, function() {
            
                    scroll = false;                    
                
                });
            }
            
            if (scrollX) {
                
                view = $window.width();
                    
                if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            
                    root = (root + view) >= $document.width() ? root : root += step;
                
                if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            
                    root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
                
                $body.stop().animate({
            
                    scrollLeft: root
                
                }, speed, option, function() {
            
                    scroll = false;
                
                });
            }
            
            return false;
            
        }).on('scroll', function() {
            
            if (scrollY && !scroll) root = $window.scrollTop();
            if (scrollX && !scroll) root = $window.scrollLeft();
            
        }).on('resize', function() {
            
            if (scrollY && !scroll) view = $window.height();
            if (scrollX && !scroll) view = $window.width();
            
        });       
    };
    
    jQuery.easing.default = function (x,t,b,c,d) {
    
       return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
       
    };
    
})(jQuery);
```